# How do I output log messages to the console

Tags: javascript, debugging, sails.js

I am working on a `sails.js` web app so I am starting the web app using the command line. I am trying to output objects to the browser console but instead, they are displayed in the command line. Is there a way to change it so that logs are output to the console?

Answer (score 3):

You can't output anything to the log in the browser directly from the server side code.

To do that you would put Javascript code in the response page, that would be executed in the browser and write to the log.

Comment: Why are you assuming the code is server side? I am calling console.log(foo) in my front end view class.

Comment: @user1457366: Simply because the output ends up in the command window. It's impossible for client side script to output anything outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tools you are using. For example, I used PHP and React and both offer features to send error messages to your page (not the console).

So if you have the time to do so, you can send the error (or whatever) message to the client and then the client uses `console.log()` to print it in the browser's console.

In most cases, though, it is viewed as *dangerous* (as in not secure) to send error messages from the server to the client. Both, PHP and React have settings with a comment saying: once in production, turn that off.

Here are the settings for PHP, found in your .ini file:

```
; The following are all the settings which are different in either the production
; or development versions of the INIs with respect to PHP's default behavior.
; Please see the actual settings later in the document for more details as to why
; we recommend these changes in PHP's behavior.

; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

As we can see, the Production Values are `Off` (don't tell clients what's failing on your server).

The main problem being that you could have an error which gives away thing such as a password (to remain simple, you should never write a clear text password anywhere).

I do not know anything about `sails.js` and I do not know whether Guffa has knowledge about whether it is or not capable of doing such magic. Either way, you could implement your own version. It can be really very practical to see error messages on the browser's side because you look at it all the time. Not so much the server console... I know. I've been there many times.